# O que é o tipo System.Void

Tags: c#, .net

Até então acreditava que `void` era apenas uma palavra-chave para indicar um método sem retorno, mas então encontrei o System.Void na MSDN. Isso muda algo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`System.Void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.void.aspx) só tem utilidade usando [`Reflection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173183.aspx), se houver desejo do programador de saber quando um método tem como retorno `void`.

A estrutura existe basicamente pra resolver questões entre compilador e CLR, em que toda primitiva pode ou não herdar de `System`. Não que necessariamente isso tenha muita utilidade na hora de escrever código.